# Antd: How to set nested field value using setFieldsValue

Tags: reactjs, antd

So I have a nested dynamic form, and I want to check its value using `getFieldsValue`. But whenever I do, it doesn't return me the values.

Using ant form hook, I create form list as `<Form.List name="guests">`
And assign the name to form input `<FormInput name={[index, "firstName"]} label='FIRST NAME'  />`

I am trying to set its value using `form.setFieldsValue({ [index, "firstName"]: [value])` but it doesnt works. Any suggestion regarding how to set path.
Strictly need to use `setFieldsValue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the `guests` array using form.getFieldValue (You can also use getFieldsValue(['guests'])?.guests).
Then you can modify and set the value like this:

```
let guests = form.getFieldValue('guests');

// Check If `guests` exist & guest is an array & it's not empty
if (guests && Array.isArray(guests) && guests.length) {
    // Check If firstName exists at that `index`
    if (guests[index]?.firstName) {
        guests[index].firstName = 'New Name';
        form.setFieldsValue({ names: guests });
    }
}
```